# Stack Overflow exception while LazyLoading via ILazyLoader Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, stack-overflow

I've got some nasty problem while trying to configure Entity Framework Core to lazy load one of navigation properties.

I am getting stack overflow exception while trying to lazy load (accessing lazy loaded) collection navigation property using injected `ILazyLoader`.

The only idea I've get about it is that EF Core is attempting to eagerly load entire hierarchy during lazy loading.

My expectation was that while lazy loading issues collection Entity Framework Core will only load a single level of dependency meaning (that attempting to get `Issues` will result in Entity Framework Core loading all of the issues along with their `Creators` and `Owners` however underlying Issues collection in those entities won't be loaded).

Am I doing something terribly wrong or is EF Core lazy loading broken and always attempts to load the entire hierarchy including nested lazy loaded properties? Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

The entities and relationship between entities are configured as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Creator)
            .WithMany(x => x.Issues);

public class BusinessUserProfile
{
    private ICollection<Issue> _issues;

    public BusinessUserProfile() {}

    public BusinessUserProfile(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    public ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _issues);
        set => _issues = value;
    }
}

public class Issue
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public BusinessUserProfile Owner { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatorId { get; set; }
    public BusinessUserProfile Creator { get; set; }
}

public class Administrator : BusinessUserProfile
{
    public Administrator() { }

    public Administrator(ILazyLoader lazyLoader) : base(lazyLoader)
    {
    }
}
```

> Stack overflow.
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer+<g__EnsureLong|42_0>d, Npgsql, Version=7.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7]](<g__EnsureLong|42_0>d ByRef)
> at ExampleProject.Application.Services.AdministratorService+d__12.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
> at ExampleProject.Infrastructure.Repository.GenericRepository`1+<GetByIdAsync>d__6[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetResult(System.__Canon) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor+<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor+d__15`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread) at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(Boolean)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1, Boolean)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNextAsync>d__20[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+d__20[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(Boolean) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Boolean>, Boolean) at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy+d__7`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()